# HorizontalScrollView not giving the exact scrolled X in android

Tags: android

I have an `HorizontalScrollView` in which I have placed an image which is 5000 pixel in width and is basically a scale. I have overridden the `onScroll()` method for the `HorizontalScrollView` to get the scrolled x distance.

When scrolling to the end of the view, the distance that I get in the distanceX parameter of `onScroll()` is not equal to the exact number of pixels by which the image is actually scrolled. Why not?

I am using API level 9.

Comment: I am using API level 9

Comment: Cannot find onScroll method in HorizontalScrollView

Comment: ya may be some very less pixels may more then what we are expecting in my case it does not affect the result...

Comment: i have used GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener to implement the onScroll method.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that you are using `GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener` to detect scrolling and you are interested in distanceX to get the total scrolled distance you need to save the x position when starting to scroll, then adjust that position based on all onScroll events. Documentation states that distanceX presents:

distanceX The distance along the X axis that has been scrolled since the last call to onScroll. This is NOT the distance between e1 and e2.

Comment: So to get the complete scrolled distace do i need to save the difference between e1 and e2 every time OnScroll is called and then add up the differences ? What adjustments do i need to do?

Comment: For what I understand of documentation that's how to do it, calculate x offset on every event and add that to start x position.

Comment: here is what i tried but it didnt work :
in the onScroll method i have written the following code
mEventDistance+= Math.abs(e2.getX()-e1.getX());
and in OnTouch of the HorizantalScrollView i save the initial X on ACTION_DOWN. But when i add up these values (mEventDistance + initialx). it does not give me the exact pixels. Can you please share some source for hint.

Comment: Hi
Got the solution for this.Thought to share it.
When we override the onScrollChanged(int x, int y, int oldX, int oldY) method the last value of x stores the exact number of pixels scrolled by the HorizantalScrollView.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help you

```
int scrollPos = (int) (horizontalScrollview.getScrollX());
```